storageActivityResultLauncher fails when put in another class
I know similar questions had been asked before but none of their answer can solve my question.
I want to grant permission "Manage External Storage" to my app and I found a useful example in google (https://medium.com/@kezzieleo/manage-external-storage-permission-android-studio-java-9c3554cf79a7). It works when I put it in the MainActivity but it crash when I put it another class with the error message shown:
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference

I tried to grant permission by clicking a button:
access_to_storage_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        CheckPermission checkPermission =
            new CheckPermission(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.this);
            checkPermission.askPermissionBox(new String[]        
            {Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    });

And it call the CheckPermission Class:
public class CheckPermission extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback
{
    private Context mycontext;
    private Activity myactivity;

    CheckPermission(Context context, Activity activity)
    {
        this.myactivity = activity;
        this.mycontext = context;
    }

    void askPermissionBox(String[] permissionArr, int requestCode)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);

        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", myactivity.getPackageName(), null);
        intent.setData(uri);
        storageActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
    }

    private ActivityResultLauncher <Intent> storageActivityResultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                                  new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result)
        {
            // Android is 11 (R) or above
            if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager())
            {
                // Manage External Storage Permissions Granted
                Log.d("TAG", "onActivityResult: Manage External Storage Permissions Granted");
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(myactivity, "Storage Permissions Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

This method works when I put it in MainActivity but it crashes when I put it in another class. I tried to refer to this example (java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread) but it does not match with my requirement as I cannot set
myActivity.storageActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);

What shall I do to fix the problem?

Get rid of CheckPermission. Put your code back in an actual activity, one that is being started by the framework and is displaying UI, such as MainActivity.
